# Как заполнить переменные через цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть несколько похожих переменных, как мне заполнить их через цикл с определенным шагом

```
line1=[(60,0),(60,1080)]
line2=[(120,0),(120,1080)]
line3=[(180,0),(180,1080)]
```

И т.д.

Comment: Для такое цели использовать отдельные переменные - это создавать себе большой геморрой в будущем. Лучше сразу создать один список line, и будут у вас подсписки line[0], line[1], line[2] и т.д

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо игры с индексами, игра с конкретными значениями по шагу:

```
step = 60
max_value = 300
items = [[(x, 0), (x, 1080)] for x in range(0, max_value + 1, step)]
print(items)

print(items[1])
# [(60, 0), (60, 1080)]

print(items[2])
# [(120, 0), (120, 1080)]

print(items[3])
# [(180, 0), (180, 1080)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> step = 60
>>> num = 6
>>> listLine = [0]*num

>>> for i in range(num):
    listLine[i] = [(step*i,0),(step*i,1080)]


>>> listLine[1]
[(60, 0), (60, 1080)]

>>> listLine[2]
[(120, 0), (120, 1080)]

>>> listLine[3]
[(180, 0), (180, 1080)]

>>> # И т.д.
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ